# variable is coming back as undefined jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to call a function in jQuery and the variable is coming back as undefined in the console

```
   var divide = function(entry) {
        var entry = number

        for (var i = 1; i <= entry; i++) {
            if (i % 5 === 0 && i % 3 === 0) {
              return "pingpong";
            } else if ( i % 3 === 0) {
              return "ping";
            } else if (i % 5 === 0 ) {
              return "pong";
            } else {
              return i;
          }
       }
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("form#number").submit(function(event){

           var number = parseInt($("#userNumber").val());
           var pingpong = divide (number);

           $("#result").text(pingpong);
           event.preventDefault();
      });

    });
```

Comment: there's no console output in the code, there's a number of variables in the code ... is this a guessing game?

Comment: a quick guess ... `number` ... it's scoped within the `document ready` - so will be undefined in `divide`

Comment: Your assignment is wrong. You are assigning `entry`, which is a function argument, to an undefined variable `number`.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need a `for-loop` for this ? Assigning number to `entry` will not help as `number` is within the local scope of `$(document).ready` which will be undefined for `divide`. As you are passing `entry` as an argument, use that for `conditions`

Try this:

```js
var divide = function(i) {
  if (i % 5 === 0 && i % 3 === 0) {
    return "pingpong";
  } else if (i % 3 === 0) {
    return "ping";
  } else if (i % 5 === 0) {
    return "pong";
  } else {
    return i;
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("form#number").submit(function(event) {
    var number = parseInt($("#userNumber").val());
    var pingpong = divide(number);
    $("#result").text(pingpong);
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id='number'>
  <input type="number" id='userNumber'>
  <input type="submit">
  <div id="result"></div>
</form>
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/kv7epmk5/)

Answer (score -1):

I think you may be confused about how arguments are passed into functions.
You have:

```
function divide ( entry ) {         // defining divide
    var entry = number;             // this line is counter-productive
    ...
}
    ....
var number;
... divide(number);                 // calling divide
```

When you call the `divide()` function, the value of the variable `number` is automatically copied into the variable `entry` in `divide()`.  Then you attempt to do the same thing with `var entry = number;` but `number` is not available in `divide()` so this fails.  Lets suppose that `number` was globally available do this line did not cause an error.  It might do what you want in this case, but a function whose argument is immediately ignored and overwritten is not very useful.  Imagine you wanted to call it with two different values:

```
divide(number);
...
divide(someothernumber);
```

that wouldn't work because of the `var entry = number;` line -- you could never successfully pass `someothernumber` into `divide()`.  Delete the line:

```
var entry = number;
```

from `divide()` and you will be much happier.

you try to delete "var entry = number"